# Want to bind reportviewer with sql query manually

Tags: c#, datagrid, reportviewer

I want to bind ReportViewer with the query I execute just like we do with DataGridView so the form will contain a textbox and a button. When I enter a student id in the text box and click the button it must fetch specific records from the table and show it in report viewer in the form of receipt. I have never worked with ReportViewer so I dont know how and where to start if you can provide me with some example or just write a rough blueprint I think I can manage.

Thanks

Comment: Nikita, Can you please share what type of reporting you are trying to build, `local report` or `server report`..

Comment: The data is stored in database and i want to show it in my form using report viewer thats it dont know about local or server

Answer (score 1):

ReportViewer displays reports, not bound data.  In order to display a receipt, you will need to create a .rdl or .rdlc file (which one depends on whether you're working in WinForms or WebForms).

Your report definition will be stored in the .rdl or .rdlc file.  You can store a query definition in the .rdl file and it will be executed when you display the report.  You can set up parameters in the query and report that you can be prompted for.

Beyond that, the specifics differ depending on whether this is a WinForms or WebForms report.

Answer (score 0):

however i can give you a hint for `Local Report` try to bind it like this, This examples accepts parameter `FromDate` and `ToDate` and fetches data accordingly using and `EntiyDataSource`..

**page.aspx**

```
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"
 Height="600px" SizeToReportContent="True"
        Width="800px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)"
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=FooEntities" DefaultContainerName="FooContainerEntities" 
        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Foo_table">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetList" TypeName="model">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="dateFrom" Type="DateTime"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="dateTo" Type="DateTime"></asp:Parameter>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListData> listData = new List<ListData>();
    DateTime dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text.Trim());
    DateTime dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text.Trim());
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
    ReportParameter[] reportParameter = new ReportParameter[2];
    reportParameter[0] = new ReportParameter("dateFrom", dateFrom.ToShortDateString());
    reportParameter[1] = new ReportParameter("dateTo", dateTo.ToShortDateString());
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameter);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();       

}
```

Comment: i m trying to generate a receipt of students admission in which i want to show only specific data fetched from database.

Comment: got it..the example i provided you, it fetches data within a date range from DB via EF...you can try with this approach...if you can show your code..that 'll be more helpful for everyone to understand..

Comment: dear mayank thanks for your help but I am working on windows form application using C# and the code you provided belongs to ASP .NET in which I am not comfortable at all.